# DialogFragment pausing a CountDownTimer

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I have two fragment alternatively replacing each other (both containing a countdowntimer), until the end of a game. I'd like to implement a pause button, who, like his name indicates, would pause the fragment underneath.

I was thinking to do that with a dialog fragment to do that smoothly but if you have another suggestion, I'm open minded.

When clicking on the button, a pause menu will appear and the countdowntimer underneath will stop. When resuming the game, it will continue where it stopped.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) class does not provide a method for pause. The best workaround for this is to save the remaining time when the pause button is clicked, and to create a new `CountDownTimer` with that amount of time when the game is unpaused.

I've done this in an app I made some time ago, where I needed to manipulate the time by adding or subtracting the time, same idea. Make the new timer, cancel the old one, and start the new one.

Comment: Yeah but with the dialog fragment on top my other fragment, it doesn't call onPause(). Can I force it ?

Comment: just call it from the button click? Right before you make the dialog fragment.